# How can I get the VPC Endpoint DNS name for Route53 in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In a CloudFormation template I want to create both a VPC Endpoint and a Route53 Record pointing to it.

This is the record definition:

```
  Domain:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      AliasTarget:
        DNSName: ---- NEED THIS VALUE ----
        HostedZoneId: !Ref HostedZoneId
      HostedZoneId: !Ref HostedZoneId
      Name: !Ref DomainName
      Type: A
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpcendpoint.html), the VPC Endpoint has an output `DnsEntries` which returns a list like `["Z1HUB23UULQXV:vpce-01abc23456de78f9g-12abccd3.ec2.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com", "Z1HUB23UULQXV:vpce-01abc23456de78f9g-12abccd3-us-east-1a.ec2.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com", "Z1C12344VYDITB0:ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"]`.

In that example, I would need for the `DNSName` the value `vpce-01abc23456de78f9g-12abccd3.ec2.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com`, that is, the first item in the list without the Hosted Zone ID.

But I don't know how to fetch that within a CloudFormation template.

I was trying the following: `!Select ['1', !Split [':', [!Select ['0', !GetAtt VPCEndpoint.DnsEntries]]]]`, but I'm getting the following error: `"[cfn-lint] E1018: Split has to be of type string or valid function for Resources/Domain/Properties/AliasTarget/DNSName/Fn::Select/1/Fn::Split"`

Comment: Have you tried this:
`!Select [1, !Split [":", [!Select [0, !GetAtt VPCEndpoint.DnsEntries]]]]`

https://github.com/aws-samples/unity-aws-ec2-mac-build-farm/blob/cf7111f27e59d59e5e1e05123cc31a03f3abd4c7/infra/CloudFormation-event/stacks/vpc.yaml

Comment: @AnthonyB. that's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: not exactly, you put single quote around the 1, 0 and :. The link I put is from AWS-samples, so should be working and it does the same thing as you.

Comment: The select/split logic looks right. Can you show us how you are using that? i.e. the full template

Comment: @Paolo already found the issue. All the required information was already in the question. The problem was a `[]` that shouldn't be used in `Split`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue.

The second argument of `Split` was wrong. It has to be a String, not a list.

This is the correct one:

```
!Select ['1', !Split [':', !Select ['0', !GetAtt VPCEndpoint.DnsEntries]]]
```

Notice there is no `[` between `,` and `!Select`.